# How to vertically position tvo divs of unknown height on top of each other to fill available page height?

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to layout two vertically positioned containers, which should fill available vertical space on a page in such a way that the top container expands vertically with content, while the bottom container takes up the remaining vertical space and overflows with scrollbar.

Here is a sketch:

[image]

I'm stuck defining the properties (especially height) of the second container. My best shot is:

```
.container {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    position: absolute; 
    height: auto;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    background:#ff8;
}

.first {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.second {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="first">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer enim mi, semper id lectus nec, tincidunt congue odio. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur tellus eros, mollis malesuada imperdiet eget, congue in nisi. Donec vel nunc id libero elementum dignissim. Nulla facilisi. Mauris laoreet bibendum vestibulum. Integer odio magna, tempus eu orci quis, dignissim blandit enim. </div>
    <div class="second">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
</div>
```

however, the second div flows below past the container instead of only stretching up to the available container space.

NOTE: what makes the problem non-trivial is that the height values of both divs are not known in advance and depend on the content! (Otherwise I'd be able to set the height manually and not bother you guys :) )

any hints on how to proceed?

Comment: What should happen if there's so much content within the top box that it could potentially take up the entire container?

Comment: @cimmanon added markup, thanks for the remark. In theory, top box will not be filled with so much content, but you do have a point. Haven't really considered it, but I guess then the second box should not be displayed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here is my solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/VRT6U/2/

**HTML**

```
div id="main"> 
<div id="top">
    fdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa 

    </div>
<div id="bot">
    bot 
    fdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsafdsafdsafdafd as fsa s asa fas fsa fsa
    </div>
</div>


<div id="addMoreText" title="click here to add more text to top element">click me!</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main {width: 200px; height: 400px; background: #EEE; border: 1px solid #CCC;}
#top  {width: 190px; margin: 5px;  background: #CCC; border: 1px solid #AAA; color: #888;}
#bot  {width: 190px; margin: 5px;  background: #CC5; border: 1px solid #AAA; color: #888; overflow: 
        -moz-scrollbars-vertical; overflow-y: scroll;}

#addMoreText { width: 100px; height: 20px; background: #06A; border: 1px solid #036; text-align:center; color:white; font-size:11px; font-weight:bold; line-height:20px; margin:20px 50px; cursor:pointer;}
```

**jQuery**

calculateBotDivHeight();

```
$('#addMoreText').click(function(){
    $('#top').html($('#top').html()+ " some text ");
    //if you load text not only on page load, you have to recalculate the height.
    calculateBotDivHeight();
});

function calculateBotDivHeight(){
    $newHeight = $('#main').height() - $('#top').outerHeight(true) - 6;
    $('#bot').height($newHeight);
}
```

Comment: This works as advertised, and as it was the first answer, I'll accept it! Adding some more tricks from @user934902 to trigger resizing on window resize does the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are gonna need to use javascript or jquery to calculate this to respond to your text. Here is a jQuery solution, use the fiddle to insert or remove text to view how the divs alter

Fiddle 1: http://jsfiddle.net/5p77w/3/ 
Fiddle 2 (more content with overflow): http://jsfiddle.net/5p77w/4/

```
var $parentH = $('.container').outerHeight();
var $firstH = $('.first').outerHeight(); 
var $applyH = $parentH - $firstH;

$('.second').css("height", $applyH);
```

you need to use `.outerHeight()` to include your margins and paddings. You calculate the height of the `.first` and subtract is from the total height of the parent. You save this number in a variable and apply it to the `.second` element using jquery `.css()`

If your site is responsive i recommend putting this in a function and setting up your page to call a function that does this height adjustment

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 changeHeights();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
 changeHeights();
});

function changeHeights() {
 var $parentH = $('.container').outerHeight();
 var $firstH = $('.first').outerHeight(); 
 var $applyH = $parentH - $firstH;

 $('.second').css("height", $applyH);
}
```

you should also consider applying a max height to the first div with an overflow in case the content exceeds the height of the parent thus making the second div usless